# UITableView reuseIdentifier: repeating elements at top and bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having trouble with my UITableView top and bottom cells alternating whenever they scroll off and back onto screen. I believe this is an issue with reuseIdentifier but I'm not sure how to get around it. PlaceTableViewCell is a subclass of ABTableViewCell from Loren Britcher for fast scrolling.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *uniqueIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PlaceTableViewCell *cell = (PlaceTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier];


    if(cell == nil){
       cell = [[PlaceTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:uniqueIdentifier];
    }

    Places *place = [self.placesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];    
    cell.place_title = place.title;
    cell.place_street = place.street;
    cell.place_thumb = place.thumb_path;


    return cell;

}
```

Edit:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.placesArray count];
}
```

From my subclass of ABTableViewCell:

```
- (void)drawContentView:(CGRect)r
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(self.selected)
    {
        backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    [backgroundColor set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, r);

    CGPoint p;
    p.x = 42;
    p.y = 2;

        NSLog(@"place_thumb: %@", place_thumb);

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:place_thumb]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [image drawAtPoint: p];


        p.x = p.x + 50;

        [textColor set];
        [place_title drawAtPoint:p withFont:place_titleFont];

        p.y = 25;

        textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [textColor set];
    [place_street drawAtPoint:p withFont:place_streetFont];

}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?

Comment: If you scroll down and scroll back to the top, the last element takes the place of the first element. If you scroll up and back down, the opposite occurs (first element becomes last)

Comment: Are they all in the same section?

Comment: Try changing the string to anything else, but as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong in the code you've shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks to be correct. You need to post all your data source methods for the UITableView. I have a hunch that the issue might be happening in your `numberOfRows` method.

Are you setting the number of rows based on the array size?
Also, are you sure your array is remaining unchanged?

Comment: The array is remaining unchanged... I also posted the drawContentView which I suspect may be the root of the problem... could the image loading with dataWithContentsOfURL on the same thread be causing a lag that would cause it to do that?

Comment: actually I tried loading a static image instead of a remote image and the problem persisted...

Comment: Hmm this is quite confusing. What happens when you set different identifiers for each cell? Just for the sake of experimentation, use the indexPath.row as the cellIdentifier. If the duplication still occurs, then we can rule out the table view's data source methods being the issue.